# button with image at left and text center aligned

Tags: css, wordpress

i am trying to make a button with an image in it and some text. i want the image to be align at left and the text to be fully centered. The text should be centered at the width of the whole button and not at the remaining width cause to the image.

i tried with span but with no success

```
<a href=#><button class="lightgray-btn rightbuttons"><span class="demoimage"><img class="btnimg" src="..." alt="" /></span><span class="demotext">"some text</span></button></a>
```

i also want to avoid the background-image:url because in mobile i am afraid that the text would be on the image

thank you

Comment: Why do you have a button inside an anchor tag?

Comment: What he says ^^... Also if you want the image on the right, why add it to the left of the text?

Comment: Use one or the other. - Create a jsfiddle with your HTML and CSS

Comment: sorry for this, i mean the image on left

Comment: [**Links are not buttons**](http://www.karlgroves.com/2013/05/14/links-are-not-buttons-neither-are-divs-and-spans/)

Answer (score 6):

This will work for you.

```css
button {
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
.btnimg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 6px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
  <button class="lightgray-btn rightbuttons">
    <img class="btnimg" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-27-24-8.jpg" alt="" />
    some text
  </button>
```

Comment: this is good but in mobile view when the width text is near the width of the button, then the text overlaps the image

Comment: It won't if you increase the padding  `padding: 15px 40px;` the 40px should be increased!

Answer (score 1):

You should not use a button for a simple link. Instead, use a link and style it. You can do it like this for example :

```css
.btn {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 6px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #af0c0c;
  color: #fff;
}
.btn img {
  float: left;
}
.btn span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="btn">
 <img src="//lorempicsum.com/futurama/50/50/2" alt="" />
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler way of doing it:

```
.myawesomebutton img
{
 float:left;
}
.myawesomebutton span
{
 position:absolute;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
 transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}

<a href="#" class="myawesomebutton">
    <img src="myawesomeimages/myawesomeimage.png"/>
    <span>My awesome button</span>
</a>
```

Comment: He said "i also want to avoid the background-image:url". ;)

Comment: exactly.in mobile the text would be on the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a minimum width for your background-image and apply the same as padding in left and right of the text. This way your text wont overlap the background-image.